# Why is react-scripts having a compile error for optional chaining?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I've upgraded `typescript` to at least 3.7 which is when optional chaining came about. `react-scripts` is also up to date. Yet the following line keeps throwing up the following error when I run `npm run build`:

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/myfile.tsx
  Line 172:25:  Parsing error: Expression expected
```

Here is the "offending" line:

```
   const result = item.get(first)?.get(second);
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{

  project details...

  "dependencies": {

    other dependencies here...

    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.5.0",
    "cross-env": "6.0.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es2020",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": false
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I don't have any squiggly lines in my IDE (VS Code), so at least that is reading it correctly.

How can I get optional chaining to play nicely here? Does `react-scripts` ignore my tsconfig.json and/or `typescript` in my package.json?

Comment: It sounds like you're using the latest version of `react-scripts` which means it's likely to support optional chaining. Is there a sample repo which is able to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error hints at what the problem was: `Parsing error`

Although `react-scripts` and `typescript` was set to the correct versions, the `eslint` package needed updating. Running `npm i eslint@^6.6` fixed the issue.